# How do I create a "vantage point" 3D render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

[image]
[image]
[image]Thank you in advance. This idea is fundamentally simple. I want the viewer to perceive depth in a rendered image. The viewer could, if their head/eyes were located appropriately, perceive that they were looking THROUGH a tablet, or watching an object project out of the tablet.
I am convinced that the plan could be simulated in 3D space, right in blender. So, simply, by knowing where your audience is standing you could create a render or animation that exploits their vantage point.

I noticed this phenomenon when watching an animation I rendered. I laid my phone on the kitchen countertop and was amazed that it appeared to pop out of the screen. I did not intend on that outcome, and I am intrigued to know how awesome it would be to exploit that optical illusion.

Comment: I don't think this is a specific Blender question, more in general how to setup a 3D scene / animation.

Comment: @Gordon I guess it could be a question on how to set up a render as if viewed from an angle not orthogonal to the viewing plane?

Comment: @RobinBetts Maybe. Since I never experienced this phenomenon so far but he did with one of his own animations, it would probably be best if he took this scene and tried to figure out what's so special about it that it might create this effect.